# Python: Scheduling event to sched with multiprocessing

Tags: python, python-3.x, scheduler, python-multiprocessing

I have multiprocessing application and want to use scheduling using sched from Python libs.
When I enter or enter absolutely event to a scheduler with any other process than the one which created the scheduler, no new event is created or at least not executed.

Here's a sample:

```
import sched, time
import multiprocessing as mp

scheduler = sched.scheduler(time.time, time.sleep)

def new_task(s):
    time.sleep(2)
    s.enter(1,1,printM, argument=('other process',))

def printM(a):
    print(a)

scheduler.enter(5, 1, printM, argument=('first, prio 1',))
scheduler.enter(5, 2, printM, argument=('second, prio 2',))

p = mp.Process(target=new_task, args=(scheduler,))
p.start()

while  not scheduler.empty():
    t = scheduler.run(blocking=False)
```

And the output:

```
first, prio 1
second, prio 2
```

I know that sched is multithread-safe but multiprocessing is not mentioned therefore i guess it's not mp-safe.
I can't redesing application to multi-threading.
Solution to add new events only in original process is not enough in my case.
An initiative to create new events have to be from different processes.
Application is using python 3.5 but for sake of Answer solution using any version would be acceptable.

Can you propose a solution for this problem?

Comment: you can also call `scheduler.run` in each new process

Comment: or you can use the scheduler to create the new process instead.